# Appium-python-client, find element function

Tags: python, python-appium

im new to the appium library and I'm facing issues with the methods to locate elements in an android app, the two methods in question are:
1- driver.find_element_by_id
2- driver.find_element

```
#desired_cap defined above
driver = web.driver.remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_cap)
driver.find_element_by_id(#element id)
```

the problem is i can't find this method. when i type it in the ide it doesn't work.
I tried using the find_element method but it didn't work too.

```
desired_cap = {
  "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "appium:appActivity": ".LandingScreen",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:appPackage": "com.myapp",
  "appium:noReset": "true"
}
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",desired_cap)

driver.find_element("AppiumBy.ID","com.talabat:id/ivToolbarAddressArrow")
```

i tried to make the second method work:
"AppiumBy.ID"
By.ID
ID
"id"
none of them made the duntion work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe you have a typo and it should read webdriver iso web.driver:

```
driver = webdriver.remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_cap)
```

To answer your question: Appium works with accessibility ID, like so:

```
driver.find_element("AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID","SomeAccessibilityID")
```

Appium documentation [here](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/)

Comment: Thank you. I did see this documentation, but i just found out that there is important part not mentioned in the doc , the AppiumBy.  must be imported first                                           
(from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy)

Comment: Imports are considered a given in most documentation I'm afraid. Great to read that you worked it out. Just remember that anytime your IDE does not recognise something, an import is missing.